# Extracting Values from a Map[String, Any] where Any is a Map itself

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a Map which contains another Map in its value field. Here is an example of some records ;

```
(8702168053422489,Map(sequence -> 5, id -> 8702168053422489, type -> List(AppExperience, Session), time -> 527780267713))
(8702170626376335,Map(trackingInfo -> Map(trackId -> 14183197, location -> Browse, listId -> 3393626f-98e3-4973-8d38-6b2fb17454b5_27331247X28X6839X1506087469573, videoId -> 80161702, rank -> 0, row -> 1, imageKey -> boxshot|AD_e01f4a50-7e2b-11e7-a327-12789459b73e|en, requestId -> 662d92c2-6a1c-41a6-8ac4-bf2ae9f1ce68-417037), id -> 8702170626376335, sequence -> 59, time -> 527780275219, type -> List(NavigationLevel, Session), view -> details))
(8702168347359313,Map(muting -> false, id -> 8702168347359313, level -> 1, type -> List(Volume)))
(8702168321522401,Map(utcOffset -> 3600, type -> List(TimeZone), id -> 8702168321522401))
(8702171157207449,Map(trackingInfo -> Map(trackId -> 14183197, location -> Browse, listId -> 3393626f-98e3-4973-8d38-6b2fb17454b5_27331247X28X6839X1506087469573, videoId -> 80161356, rank -> 0, row -> 1, imageKey -> boxshot|AD_e01f4a50-7e2b-11e7-a327-12789459b73e|en, requestId -> 662d92c2-6a1c-41a6-8ac4-bf2ae9f1ce68-417037), id -> 8702171157207449, sequence -> 72, startOffset -> 0, time -> 527780278061, type -> List(StartPlay, Action, Session)))
```

The actual records I've interested in are the ones that contain `trackingInfo`, records 2 and 5.

What I would like to do is extract those and then extract some of the keys from there such as `trackId`. Something like this;

```
val trackingInfo = json("trackingInfo").asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]
val videoId = trackingInfo("videoId").asInstanceOf[Int]
val id = json("id").asInstanceOf[Long]
val sequence = json("sequence").asInstanceOf[Int]
val time = json("time").asInstanceOf[Long]
val eventType = json.get("type").getOrElse(List("")).asInstanceOf[List[String]]
```

To the extract the inner map, I've tired;
    `myMap.map {case (k,v: collection.Map[_,_]) => v.toMap case _ => }`

Which brings back the inner map but as a `scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[Any]` which leaves me in a puzzle on extracting values from it.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Just a general comment. Use of .asInstanceOf is not safe. Could cause problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a real map (I cut it a little bit)

```
val data: Map[ BigInt, Any ] = Map(
    BigInt( 8702168053422489L ) -> Map("sequence" -> "5", "id" -> BigInt( 8702168053422489L ) ),
    BigInt( 8702170626376335L ) -> Map("trackingInfo" -> Map("trackId" -> BigInt( 14183197 ), "location" -> "Browse" ), "id" -> BigInt( 8702170626376335L ) ),
    BigInt( 8702168347359313L ) -> Map("id" -> BigInt( 8702168347359313L ) ),
    BigInt( 8702168321522401L ) -> Map("id" -> BigInt( 8702168321522401L ) ),
    BigInt( 8702171157207449L ) -> Map("trackingInfo" -> Map("trackId" -> BigInt( 14183197 ), "location" -> "Browse" ), "id" -> BigInt( 8702171157207449L ) )
)
```

And you want to get records which have a `trackingInfo` key

```
val onlyWithTracking = data.filter( ( row ) => { 

    val recordToFilter = row._2 match {
        case trackRecord: Map[ String, Any ] => trackRecord
        case _ => Map( "trackId" -> Map() )
    }

    recordToFilter.contains( "trackingInfo" ) 
} )
```

And then process those records in some way

```
onlyWithTracking.foreach( ( row ) => {

    val record = row._2 match {
        case trackRecord: Map[ String, Any ] => trackRecord
        case _ => Map( "trackingInfo" -> Map() )
    }

    val trackingInfo = record( "trackingInfo" ) match {
        case trackRow: Map[ String, Any ] => trackRow
        case _ => Map( "trackId" -> "error" )
    }

    val trackId = trackingInfo( "trackId" )

    println( trackId )
} )
```

With this pattern matching I'm trying to ensure that using keys like `trackingInfo` or `trackId` is somewhat safe. You should implement more strict approach.

Comment: thanks for your reply. however remember that the original Map is `Map[String,Any]` so when doing `val onlyWithTracking = data.filter( ( row ) => row._2.contains( "trackingInfo" ) )` I get the error `value contains is not a member of Any`

Comment: Yeah. I edited the answer to address that. A bit more pattern matching.

Comment: thanks for that, I seem to get this error on the processing bit `scala.math.BigInt cannot be cast to java.lang.String`.

Comment: Are you sure that your big map is `[String, Any]`, not the `[BigInt, Any]`?

Comment: id part looks like `BigInt` so you could try changing the `trackRecord: Map[ String, Map[ String, Any ] ]` to `trackRecord: Map[ BigInt, Map[ String, Any ] ]`.

Comment: ok if I change my `trackRecord` in `val record` to `case trackRecord: Map[ BigInt, Map[ String, Any ] ] => trackRecord` then how would I pattern match afterwards, currently it is `val trackingInfo = record( "trackingInfo" ) match {` but this gives a type mismatch error

Comment: I think I found where was the problem. I changed the main map keys to `BigInts` and everything went well but when I changed `trackId` to `BigInt` I got the same error. Switching last pattern matching to `Map[String, Any]` helped. I updated the answer.

Comment: also how can I store the fields in a structure, as I want to do more than just printing them out ?

Comment: Safety. Pattern matching let you do something practical with the object when it cannot be used as a proposed class instance. Imagine you get a map where the keys are BigInts so you can't use it as `Map[String, Any]`. Pattern matching will fallback to the error object (or throw more comprehensible error message) rather than throwing default error.

Comment: Just use `map` instead of `foreach` and inside it return required object like Map or Tuple. `val trackMap = onlyWithTracking.map( ... `